EF Core tries to create a new foreign key when one is already defined
I have two classes that are linked by the foreign key PickingListId. They are both drawing data from SQL views, so I've renamed my PickingList to PickingListView. It worked fine before as it seemed to be guessing the foreign key correctly (PickingListId). However now it's trying to guess that the foreign key as PickingListViewId, so I've tried to explicitly mark the foreign key.
Here are my two classes. I've had [Key] and [ForeignKey] annotations which I've removed, believing that they might be clashing with Fluent API.
public class PickingListView
{
    public int PickingListId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PickingListLine> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class PickingListLine
{
    public int PickingListLineId { get; set; }
    public int PickingListId { get; set; }
    public PickingListView PickingListView { get; set; }
}

This is my Fluent API configuration:
modelBuilder.Entity<PickingListView>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.ToView("view_PickingList").HasKey(e => e.PickingListId);
                    entity.HasMany(e => e.Lines)
                          .WithOne(e => e.PickingListView)
                          .HasForeignKey(e => e.PickingListId)
                          .IsRequired();
                });
modelBuilder.Entity<PickingListLine>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToView("view_PickingListLine").HasKey(e => e.PickingListLineId);
                entity.Property(e => e.PickingListId)
                      .HasColumnName("PickingListId");
                entity.HasOne(e => e.PickingListView)
                      .WithMany(e => e.Lines)
                      .HasForeignKey(e => e.PickingListId);
            });

Since adding the the configuration to PickingListLine in Fluent API, I now get this error

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'PickingListId1'.

I've had a look at the generated SQL and the joins are correctly using PickingListId, however it's trying to select a PickingListId1 column, which does not exist.
How do I correctly mark the PickingListLine's PickingListId as the foreign key to link to the PickingListView class?

Based on your error message, your fluent API configuration is incorrect.  You should explicitly defining the foreign key column. You can define your relation by adding entity.Property(e => e.PickingListId).HasColumnName("PickingListId");  In addition, make sure that the PickingListId is consistently named across your entities and SQL views.

Just to clarify that the SQL entities are correctly named, the following SQL query does return results:
Select * From view_PickingList pl INNER JOIN view_PickinglistLIne pll on pl.PickingListID = pll.PickingListID
I've also tried adding entity.Property(e => e.PickingListId).HasColumnName("PickingListId");
however it has not changed anything.

The two configuration statements entity.HasMany... and entity.HasOne... are redundant. Remove one of them. They seem correct though. The code you show doesn't indicate any reason for EF to make up this column name. It seems that another relationship is involved that you don't show.

Remove the .Property().HasColumnName() and the .HasOne().WithMany() on the PickingListLine config. Relationships should only be configured from one side or the other, not both.  Typos can end up creating weird mapping issues, so avoid unnecessary config statements.

It turns out that the problem was that when I separated the PickingListView and PickingList classes that I left the ICollection<PickingListLine> Lines reference in PickingList, which caused EF Core to generate the extra foreign key.
I've removed the reference (As PickingList will be using a non-view version of the lines) and it's now working correctly.
Apologies for asking an unanswerable question, it didn't even occur to me to include the PickingList class.

1

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'PickingListId1'.

This error indicates that the SQL statement generated by Entity Framework Core is using a non-existent column, PickingListId1. This is typically due to incorrect configuration or duplication issues.
Make sure your column names are spelled correctly.
2

entity.Property(e => e.PickingListId).HasColumnName("PickingListId");

If the column names in the database are the same as the property names, you can omit the HasColumnName configuration.

This is typically due to incorrect configuration or duplication issues -- Yeah...

I can confirm that the names of the columns are all correct, as the SQL query Select * From view_PickingList pl INNER JOIN view_PickinglistLIne pll on pl.PickingListID = pll.PickingListID is returning results.
